# Mass change attribute, with check box and a select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On the index page of Users, my application lists all the user's names(string) and if that particular user is active (boolean). On this page I would like to be able to select multiple users, using checkboxes, then using a select box, select true or false. The application should then update all the users who were checked to that boolean attribute. How do you accomplish this with Rails 3? I can supply some of my code if necessary, but I didn't think anything didn't explain it's self. Thanks.

Comment: Use update_all and check_box_tag with ids.
Example : User.update_all({:active => true}, {:id => ids})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :users do
  post 'setup', :on => :collection
end
```

Your `UserController`

```
def setup
  @ids = params[:users][:ids]
  User.where("id IN ? ", @ids).update_all(active: true)
end
```

Supply `@users = User.all` in your view and add following form:

```
=form_tag setup_users_path do
  -@users.each do |user|
    =check_box_tag "users[ids][]", user.id
    =user.name
  =submit_tag "SETUP"
```

This is rough idea of how I would have done it. I just wrote away the code above without testing in my machine; prone to some errors.

Hope it helps. :)